# Show element outline only on tab but not on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

If I go to the [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org) and tab through the dropdowns I get elements with outline which is totally fine for accessibility:

[image]

But if I click on it, I dont get the outline:

[image]

I have tried achieving this by using only pseudoclass :focus, excluiding :active yet it still doesn't work:

```
a {
  color: @brand-link;

  &:focus:not(:active) {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
  }
  &:active {
    outline: none;
  }

}
```

Anyone knows how to achieve outline strictly only for tab navigation but not for clicked element?

I'm using less by the way.

Here an example, if you click on it it will outline it `gold` colored:

```css
a:focus {
   outline: 4px solid gold;
}

a:active {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="/">FOO LINK</a>
```

I want gold color just visible on tab navigation but not when clicking the element

Comment: `outline:none;`?

Comment: in ur css outline:none;

Comment: @Pete, yup I already tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: can u provide the html code

Comment: So you don't want the outline to show or you want to show it? Your question and people commenting are different views. Clicking on that link on Mozilla website leads to another page so there's no point it should show any outline after the page reloads.

Comment: @TheUnKnown I think this part makes it clear people are just not reading: "Anyone knows how to achieve outline strictly only for tab navigation but not for clicked element?"

Comment: @CommonSenseCode we are most certainly reading; you are not making your question clear and constantly editing it.

Comment: If I go to MDN, tabbing will not get me to the menus, to access the dropdowns. It is very unclear what you are asking, besides wanting different :active/:focus styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:active` is the pseudo class that fires on click.

```
a:link:active{outline:10px dotted #000;}
```

will show exactly this onclick. [jsfiddle for you to see](https://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/dfvj3uLc/6/).
[Very informative post on differences between `:hover`, `:active`, and `:focus`](https://bitsofco.de/when-do-the-hover-focus-and-active-pseudo-classes-apply/).

`:link` represents an element that has not yet been visited. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link)

EDIT:
Solution is then:

```
a:focus:not(:link:active) {  
outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;  
}
```

Comment: Hi albert thanks for the answer what I want is when you tab on an element to show its default outline, but on click do not show this outline

Comment: actually it seems your answer is the solution using link solved the problem

Comment: This is what worked: `a:focus:not(:link:active) {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
  }`

Comment: that is wild, because in my head it shouldn't work. that doesn't mean i'm right, by any means. at least you got your answer.

Comment: I read the docu and it says for unvisited elements yet it works at least in chrome and FFox :/

Comment: its working in ff for me. don't forget about `:visited` if you want to add more styles.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who needs it, here is a (quite modern) solution that uses `:focus-visible` instead of `:focus` (the link does not go anywhere so that you can see the solution in action):

```css
a:focus-visible {
   outline: 4px solid gold;
}

a:active {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)">FOO LINK</a>
```

If you try to tab to the element in the snippet above, the outline will show up; if you try clicking it directly, the outline will *not* be shown.

**What it does -**
`:focus-visible` functions the same as `:focus`, except while `:focus` is applied to a focused element no matter what, `:focus-visible` lets the browser determine (through some calculations) whether styling for the focused element is needed.

**Why it's needed -**
So for example, let's say you're an average joe, don't have any reason to press the [tab] key, and use your mouse to click things on a webpage; you wouldn't need to see an outline around everything you click, would you? It wouldn't be helpful in your case, and it simply might not look nice to just have this outline appear around everything. In this case it would seem suitable to use `:focus` and remove the outline. No one needs it, right?

***BUT*** then let's say you are a person that navigates webpages using only your keyboard, and/or you utilize accessibility tools like screen reader; then, in your case, it would be *very* helpful (and likely quite necessary) to see what you have selected. If you weren't able to know what you're focused on, you would hardly be able to know what you're doing!

With these people in mind, unless you want to make your website inaccessible for a decent amount of the population, your only choice (using `:focus`) is to show an outline, even if it is unnecessary for the user. *Ugh. Even after styling the outline it just doesn't look good for my page. I don't know where I would start trying to program this either. If only there was a built-in pseudo-class for this...*

...that's what `:focus-visible` is for! It figures out (by itself, no JavaScript necessary) if the user needs an element to have a different appearance when it's focused! Click things with your mouse? Don't use your keyboard to navigate the page? No styling applied! Navigate pages with your keyboard? Need to know what you have selected? Here's some styling!

**Documentation -**
I can't explain it any better than that, so for more clarification and information on this, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible#focus_vs_focus-visible. The internet can tell you everything you need to know about this.

**Compatibility -**
If you're worried about [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible#browser_compatibility), yes, this is a relatively new feature (likely why this wasn't mentioned in previous answers, although they weren't too long ago). See [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Afocus-visible) for some specifics. Also, please check out the [Accessibility concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible#accessibility_concerns) section of the documentation. It specifies some requirements for styling outlines to keep them accessible for everyone while making them fit your page.

I hope this answer helps someone! :D

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
a {
  color: @brand-link;

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

}
```

Comment: This breaks accessibility, and therefore doesn't answer the author's question. See https://medium.com/better-programming/a11y-never-remove-the-outlines-ee4efc7a9968